# mass change link in html website

Tags: html, nested, replace

I took over an old HTML based site with all hard coded links, no frames etc.  Theres who knows how many pages that have a link to abc.html (<--example).

I've been asked to go through the pages and change the abc.html link to 123.html (<--another example).

I could download the entire site from via FTP then use find and replace to go through all the files, then upload the changes.

Problem is the site is poorly organized and heavily nested so theres probably several hundred mg of junk I'd have to download just to be sure.

The other option is to change the html code of abc.html and put in something like

> We've moved, you are currently being
>   redirected.

And use some sort of redirect.

Anyone have any other ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a list of all the files that contained the old link using

```
grep -lir "some text" *
```

(above taken from [comandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2244/find-files-containing-text#comment))

I then used the following command to replace all the matching text accordingly.

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sed -ir 's/old/new/g' {} \;
```

(also taken from [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/223/a-find-and-replace-within-text-based-files-to-locate-and-rewrite-text-en-mass.#comment))

I used the sed version as it created backups of the html files and named them *.htmlr

Not ideal as I now have more junk, but I can easily delete them with

```
rm *.htmlr
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a software such as [Actual Search and Replace](http://www.divlocsoft.com/) ?

Comment: Looks like it would work, BUT, I'd have to mount the FTP server as a local directory

Comment: Or download the files locally, yes. Is that a big issue?

Comment: It is, because there's tons of old junk on the server that I don't want to sift through.  Actual Search & Replace seems to be working.  I'm running it under wine and used curlftpfs to mount the ftp server as local FS.  The speed is decent and it's nearly done going through all the files.  It looks like it'll work.  Once it does I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 2):

You will need to return [HTTP 301 Moved Permanently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) on old links so that the search engines know that the content has moved and not just disappeared.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll make a note of that.

Comment: For SEO (Search Engine Optimization), you should do this as well.